# Firebase Stream bug, a custom class rideDetails.dart is not being recognized in the database.dart file

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

First of all apologies, I didn't know how to phrase the title.

Basically I have this class:

```
class rideDetails{

  final String name;
  final String seats;
  final String distance;
  final String departure;
  final String destination;
  final String date;
  final bool limit;

  rideDetails({this.name,this.seats,this.distance,this.departure,this.destination,this.date,this.limit});

}
```

And I want to use this in my database services dart file, I've included the whole code since I'm not sure what's causing the problem.

```
import 'package:carpoolapp/models/rideDetails.dart';
import 'package:carpoolapp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart'; // For File Upload To Firestore
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

class DatabaseService{

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  // collection reference
  final CollectionReference usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  final Reference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

  // images
  File _image;
  String _uploadedFileURL;


  Future updateUserData(String name) async {
    return await usersCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'name': name,
    });
  }

  Future updateImagePath(String path) async {
    return await usersCollection.doc(uid).update({
      'path': path,
    });
  }

  Future updateTripDetails(String seats, String date, String distance, bool limit, String departure, String destination) async {
    return await usersCollection.doc(uid).update({
      'seats': seats,
      'date' : date,
      'distance' : distance,
      'limit' : limit,
      'departure' : departure,
      'destination' : destination,
    });
  }

  Future getLimit() async {
    return await usersCollection.doc(uid).get().then<dynamic>((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async {
      if(snapshot.data()['limit'] == null){
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

  Future getProfile() async {
    return await usersCollection.doc(uid).get().then<dynamic>((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async {
      if(snapshot.data()['name'] == null){
        print("No name exists");
      }
      else {
        return snapshot.data()['name'];
      }
    });
  }

  // userData from snapshot
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: snapshot.data()['name'],
    );
  }

  // upload profile picture to firebase
  Future uploadPic(BuildContext context, File image) async{
    if(image != null) {
      String fileName = Path.basename(image.path);
      UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.child(uid).putFile(image);
    } else{
      return null;
    }
  }

  // ride list from snapshot
  List<rideDetails> _rideDetailsListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return rideDetails(
        name: doc.data()['name'],
        date: doc.data()['date'],
        departure: doc.data()['departure'],
        destination: doc.data()['destination'],
        distance: doc.data()['distance'],
        seats: doc.data()['seats'],
        limit: doc.data()['limit'],
      );
    }
    ).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<rideDetails>> get rideDetails{
    return usersCollection.snapshots().map(_rideDetailsListFromSnapshot);
  }

  // get user doc stream
Stream<UserData> get userData{
    return usersCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
}

}
```

Now the rideDetails class is not being recognized here even after importing it several times. However, the weird thing is when I remove the Stream code, the class is instantly recognized but when I include it, the class isn't recognized. And I do not believe the problem might be with the code itself(Although it could be) because I'm essentially doing the same thing with the UserData class in the same file and that is working perfectly. I've also tried creating the rideDetails class inside the database services file but that isn't solving the problem. I've also restarted android studio several times and commands such as flutter clean. Can anyone help me figure it out?

```
// ride list from snapshot
  List<rideDetails> _rideDetailsListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return rideDetails(
        name: doc.data()['name'],
        date: doc.data()['date'],
        departure: doc.data()['departure'],
        destination: doc.data()['destination'],
        distance: doc.data()['distance'],
        seats: doc.data()['seats'],
        limit: doc.data()['limit'],
      );
    }
    ).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<rideDetails>> get rideDetails{
    return usersCollection.snapshots().map(_rideDetailsListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

Comment: You have a class named `rideDetails` *and* a getter named `rideDetails`, which results in a name collision.  Following the common practice is of naming classes with an initial uppercase character would avoid this.  If you're unwilling to change the names, you will need to do `import 'package:carpoolapp/models/rideDetails.dart' as somePrefix;` and then use `somePrefix.rideDetails` when referring to the class.

Comment: That seems to have solved the issue thanks.